# Is there a way to get properties which has set method?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class which contains properties. Some of them are just getters that creates necessary information for me.

In one of my BLs service i am currently creating a mapper to my entity from another's api dictionary with some Reflection methods. Main problem is that there is no easy to find solution for separation properties without set method from those which does have it.

I checked `BindingFlags` but didnt find any that suits for this case. Sure there must be an in-built solution for it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the getter and setter information from the property itself in this way:

```cs
var properties = mytype.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var item in properties)
{
    if (item.CanRead)
    {
        // has at least the getter
    }
    if (item.CanWrite)
    {
        // has at least the setter
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: You are welcome. Alternatively, you could use GetGetMethod()!= null and GetSetMethod()!= null, however this is cleaner IMHO.